# parsing JSON data with PHP....large dataset

Tags: php, json

below is the dataset I am trying to parse and put into db... I am using this code

```
$json = json_decode($string);
$json[0]['segments']['layover'] gives access error...
```

also sizeof($json) returns nothing...

$json doesn't return null,is checked, prints with echo var_dump($json)

I have attempted to foreach through this...doesn't work.. tried an array type and is saying that I am illegal access stdIN object...is there anything as easy as DOMDocument() to walk through json?

---json

```
[{"legs":[{"segments":[{"layover":{"hours":1,"minutes":28},"totalTravelingTime":{"hours":1,"minutes":10},"departureAirport":{"airportCode":"ABE","airportCity":"Allentown","airportName":"Allentown (ABE)","airportCityState":"Allentown, PA"},"arrivalAirport":{"airportCode":"IAD","airportCity":"Washington","airportName":"Washington (IAD)","airportCityState":"Washington, DC"},"departureDate":1328811900000,"arrivalDate":1328816100000,"flightNumber":"3866","elapsedNumberOfDays":0,"departureDateTime":{"month":2,"year":2012,"timeZone":"GMT-05:00","day":9,"second":0,"minute":25,"hour":10,"milliSecond":0,"xsdTimeType":"DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE","dateTimeString":"2012-02-09T10:25:00-05:00"},"segmentLegSequenceIndex":1,"airCarrierCode":"UA","aircraftType":"Saab 340/340B","aircraftCode":"SF3","airline":{"activeState":"ACTIVE","airlineCode":"UA","airlineName":"UNITED","majorAirline":true,"imageFilename":"UA.gif","preferredAirline":false},"bookingCode":"S","cabinClass":"3","seatMapAvailable":true,"segmentSequenceIndex":1,"formattedDepartureTime":"10:25am","formattedArrivalTime":"11:35am","operatedBy":"/UNITED EXPRESS/COLGAN AIR","formattedDepartureDate":"2/9/12","formattedArrivalDate":"2/9/12","operatingAirlineCode":"","wiFiAvailable":false},{"layover":{"hours":1,"minutes":5},"totalTravelingTime":{"hours":3,"minutes":27},"departureAirport":{"airportCode":"IAD","airportCity":"Washington","airportName":"Washington (IAD)","airportCityState":"Washington, DC"},"arrivalAirport":{"airportCode":"DFW","airportCity":"Dallas","airportName":"Dallas (Dallas-Fort Worth Intl.)","airportCityState":"Dallas, TX"},"departureDate":1328821380000,"arrivalDate":1328830200000,"flightNumber":"3801","elapsedNumberOfDays":0,"departureDateTime":{"month":2,"year":2012,"timeZone":"GMT-05:00","day":9,"second":0,"minute":3,"hour":13,"milliSecond":0,"xsdTimeType":"DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE","dateTimeString":"2012-02-09T13:03:00-05:00"},"segmentLegSequenceIndex":1,"airCarrierCode":"UA","aircraftType":"Canadian Regional Jet 700","aircraftCode":"CR7","airline":{"activeState":"ACTIVE","airlineCode":"UA","airlineName":"UNITED","majorAirline":true,"imageFilename":"UA.gif","preferredAirline":false},"bookingCode":"S","cabinClass":"3","seatMapAvailable":true,"segmentSequenceIndex":2,"formattedDepartureTime":"1:03pm","formattedArrivalTime":"3:30pm","operatedBy":"/UNITED EXPRESS/MESA AIRLINES","formattedDepartureDate":"2/9/12","formattedArrivalDate":"2/9/12","operatingAirlineCode":"","wiFiAvailable":false},{"totalTravelingTime":{"hours":0,"minutes":50},"departureAirport":{"airportCode":"DFW","airportCity":"Dallas","airportName":"Dallas (Dallas-Fort Worth Intl.)","airportCityState":"Dallas, TX"},"arrivalAirport":{"airportCode":"ABI","airportCity":"Abilene","airportName":"Abilene (ABI)","airportCityState":"Abilene, TX"},"departureDate":1328834100000,"arrivalDate":1328837100000,"flightNumber":"2975","elapsedNumberOfDays":0,"departureDateTime":{"month":2,"year":2012,"timeZone":"GMT-06:00","day":9,"second":0,"minute":35,"hour":16,"milliSecond":0,"xsdTimeType":"DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE","dateTimeString":"2012-02-09T16:35:00-06:00"},"segmentLegSequenceIndex":1,"airCarrierCode":"AA","aircraftType":"Embraer RJ145","aircraftCode":"ER4","airline":{"activeState":"ACTIVE","airlineCode":"AA","airlineName":"American Airlines","majorAirline":true,"imageFilename":"AA.gif","preferredAirline":false},"bookingCode":"L","cabinClass":"3","seatMapAvailable":true,"segmentSequenceIndex":3,"formattedDepartureTime":"4:35pm","formattedArrivalTime":"5:25pm","operatedBy":"/AMERICAN EAGLE","formattedDepartureDate":"2/9/12","formattedArrivalDate":"2/9/12","operatingAirlineCode":"","wiFiAvailable":false}],"carriers":["UA","UA","AA"],"departureDateTime":{"month":2,"year":2012,"timeZone":"GMT-05:00","day":9,"second":0,"minute":25,"hour":10,"milliSecond":0,"xsdTimeType":"DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE","dateTimeString":"2012-02-09T10:25:00-05:00"},"arrivalDateTime":{"month":2,"year":2012,"timeZone":"GMT-06:00","day":9,"second":0,"minute":25,"hour":17,"milliSecond":0,"xsdTimeType":"DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE","dateTimeString":"2012-02-09T17:25:00-06:00"},"airLineImageFilePath":"","elapsedDays":0,"departureTime":"2012/02/09 10:25:00 PST","arrivalTime":"2012/02/09 17:25:00 PST","departureDate":1328811900000,"arrivalDate":1328837100000,"arrivalAirport":{"airportCode":"ABI","airportCity":"Abilene","airportName":"Abilene (ABI)","airportCityState":"Abilene, TX"},"legSequenceIndex":1,"departureAirport":{"airportCode":"ABE","airportCity":"Allentown","airportName":"Allentown (ABE)","airportCityState":"Allentown, PA"},"departureDateFormat":"2012/02/09","arrivalDateFormat":"Feb. 9","formattedDepartureTime":"10:25am","formattedArrivalTime":"5:25pm","hasTrainLeg":false,"stops":2,"totalTravelingHours":{"hours":8,"minutes":0},"formattedMiles":"1,495","hasBusLeg":false,"formattedDepartureDate":"2/9/12","formattedDepartureDateTime":"2/9/12","departureDateFormat1":"Thu. Feb. 9","formattedArrivalDate":"2/9/12","durationTimeInMins":480,"locationDistanceCount":1495,"locationDistanceUnit":"miles","seatMapAvailableForAnySegment":true,"firstBagFreeAirlines":false,"showOBFeeMessageForLeg":false,"airlineWithBagFeeMsg":false,"airlineWithNoBagFeeMsg":false,"legIndex":1}],"inboundLegsInfo":[{"taxes":43.22,"basePrice":808.01,"taxesAndFees":50.22,"ceilTotalPrice":859.0,"localeFormattedTaxAndFees":"$50","localeFormatBasePrice":"$808","bookingFee":7.0,"t":858.23,"ft":"$858","fab":"$808","fat":"$858","faf":"$50","tripId":30,"s":2,"c":"AA"},{"taxes":43.22,"basePrice":1028.01,"taxesAndFees":50.22,"ceilTotalPrice":1079.0,"localeFormattedTaxAndFees":"$50","localeFormatBasePrice":"$1,028","bookingFee":7.0,"t":1078.23,"ft":"$1,078","fab":"$1,028","fat":"$1,078","faf":"$50","tripId":50,"s":2,"c":"UA"}],"airFareBasisCode":"SA0MN","flightFareType":"PUBLISHED","seatCount":1,"totalPrice":858.23,"fare":{"maxLccPrice":0.0,"minLccPrice":0.0,"totalFlightFare":858.23,"currencyCode":"USD","fees":{"amount":7.00,"currency":"USD","double":7.0,"currencyCode":"USD"},"taxes":{"amount":43.22,"currency":"USD","double":43.22,"currencyCode":"USD"},"baseFare":{"amount":808.01,"currency":"USD","double":808.01,"currencyCode":"USD"},"totalFare":{"amount":858.23,"currency":"USD","double":858.23,"currencyCode":"USD"},"totalBaseFare":808.01,"localeTotalBaseFare":"$808","localeTotalFlightTaxes":"$43","totalFlightTaxes":43.22,"localeTotalFlightFare":"$858","localeTotalFees":"$7","localeTotalFlightTaxesAndFees":"$50","totalFees":7.0,"totalTaxesAndFees":{"amount":50.22,"currency":"USD","double":50.22,"currencyCode":"USD"},"flightFare":{"currencyCode":"USD","basePrice":808.01,"taxes":43.22}},"flightId":"30","showFareDisplayName":false,"fareDisplayName":"Published","firstBagFreeAirline":false,"operatedByFeeDisplayFeatureEnabled":false,"hasFare":true,"localeFormatAvgBasePrice":"$808","localeFormatAvgTotalPrice":"$858","stops":2,"bargainFare":false,"fareName":"published","selectedFlightPara":"30:30:FLTIStr","fareTypeCode":"P","airProviderId":2,"ccfeeAirline":"","displayLCCFareName":false,"noOfTicketsLeft":7,"seatPreview":true,"localeFormatAvgTotalTaxesAndFees":"$50","priceIllegal":false,"fareTypeValue":"1","showOBFeeMessageForModule":false,"completeTrip":false,"hasAirlineWithBagFee":false,"hasAirlineWithNoBagFee":false,"isABestTrip":true,"carrierList":["AA"],"isFirstBagFreePos":true},{"legs":[{"segments":[{"layover":{"hours":1,"minutes":41},"totalTravelingTime":{"hours":2,"minutes":22},"departureAirport":{"airportCode":"ABE","airportCity":"Allentown","airportName":"Allentown (ABE)","airportCityState":"Allentown, PA"},"arrivalAirport":{"airportCode":"ATL","airportCity":"Atlanta","airportName":"Atlanta (Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta Intl.)","airportCityState":"Atlanta, GA"},"departureDate":1328818020000,"arrivalDate":1328826540000,"flightNumber":"4355","elapsedNumberOfDays":0,"departureDateTime":{"month":2,"year":2012,"timeZone":"GMT-05:00","day":9,"second":0,"minute":7,"hour":12,"milliSecond":0,"xsdTimeType":"DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE","dateTimeString":"2012-02-09T12:07:00-05:00"},"segmentLegSequenceIndex":1,"airCarrierCode":"DL","aircraftType":"Canadair RJ","aircraftCode":"CRJ","airline":{"activeState":"ACTIVE","airlineCode":"DL","airlineName":"Delta","majorAirline":true,"imageFilename":"DL.gif","preferredAirline":false},"bookingCode":"Q","cabinClass":"3","seatMapAvailable":true,"segmentSequenceIndex":1,"formattedDepartureTime":"12:07pm","formattedArrivalTime":"2:29pm","operatedBy":"/PINNACLE DBA DELTA CONNECTION","formattedDepartureDate":"2/9/12","formattedArrivalDate":"2/9/12","operatingAirlineCode":"9E","wiFiAvailable":false},{"layover":{"hours":1,"minutes":5},"totalTravelingTime":{"hours":2,"minutes":30},"departureAirport":{"airportCode":"ATL","airportCity":"Atlanta","airportName":"Atlanta (Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta Intl.)","airportCityState":"Atlanta, GA"},"arrivalAirport":{"airportCode":"DFW","airportCity":"Dallas","airportName":"Dallas (Dallas-Fort Worth Intl.)","airportCityState":"Dallas, TX"},"departureDate":1328832600000,"arrivalDate":1328838000000,"flightNumber":"1810","elapsedNumberOfDays":0,"departureDateTime":{"month":2,"year":2012,"timeZone":"GMT-05:00","day":9,"second":0,"minute":10,"hour":16,"milliSecond":0,"xsdTimeType":"DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE","dateTimeString":"2012-02-09T16:10:00-05:00"},"segmentLegSequenceIndex":1,"airCarrierCode":"DL","aircraftType":"Boeing 757-200","aircraftCode":"752","airline":{"activeState":"ACTIVE","airlineCode":"DL","airlineName":"Delta","majorAirline":true,"imageFilename":"DL.gif","preferredAirline":false},"bookingCode":"Q","cabinClass":"3","seatMapAvailable":true,"segmentSequenceIndex":2,"formattedDepartureTime":"4:10pm","formattedArrivalTime":"5:40pm","operatedBy":"","formattedDepartureDate":"2/9/12","formattedArrivalDate":"2/9/12","operatingAirlineCode":"","wiFiAvailable":false},{"totalTravelingTime":{"hours":0,"minutes":50},"departureAirport":{"airportCode":"DFW","airportCity":"Dallas","airportName":"Dallas (Dallas-Fort Worth Intl.)","airportCityState":"Dallas, TX"},"arrivalAirport":{"airportCode":"ABI","airportCity":"Abilene","airportName":"Abilene (ABI)","airportCityState":"Abilene, TX"},"departureDate":1328841900000,"arrivalDate":1328844900000,"flightNumber":"2773","elapsedNumberOfDays":0,"departureDateTime":{"month":2,"year":2012,"timeZone":"GMT-06:00","day":9,"second":0,"minute":45,"hour":18,"milliSecond":0,"xsdTimeType":"DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE","dateTimeString":"2012-02-09T18:45:00-06:00"},"segmentLegSequenceIndex":1,"airCarrierCode":"AA","aircraftType":"Embraer EMB-140","aircraftCode":"ERD","airline":{"activeState":"ACTIVE","airlineCode":"AA","airlineName":"American Airlines","majorAirline":true,"imageFilename":"AA.gif","preferredAirline":false},"bookingCode":"L","cabinClass":"3","seatMapAvailable":true,"segmentSequenceIndex":3,"formattedDepartureTime":"6:45pm","formattedArrivalTime":"7:35pm","operatedBy":"/AMERICAN EAGLE","formattedDepartureDate":"2/9/12","formattedArrivalDate":"2/9/12","operatingAirlineCode":"","wiFiAvailable":false}],"carriers":["DL","DL","AA"],"departureDateTime":{"month":2,"year":2012,"timeZone":"GMT-05:00","day":9,"second":0,"minute":7,"hour":12,"milliSecond":0,"xsdTimeType":"DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE","dateTimeString":"2012-02-09T12:07:00-05:00"},"arrivalDateTime":{"month":2,"year":2012,"timeZone":"GMT-06:00","day":9,"second":0,"minute":35,"hour":19,"milliSecond":0,"xsdTimeType":"DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE","dateTimeString":"2012-02-09T19:35:00-06:00"},"airLineImageFilePath":"","elapsedDays":0,"departureTime":"2012/02/09 12:07:00 PST","arrivalTime":"2012/02/09 19:35:00 PST","departureDate":1328818020000,"arrivalDate":1328844900000,"arrivalAirport":{"airportCode":"ABI","airportCity":"Abilene","airportName":"Abilene (ABI)","airportCityState":"Abilene, TX"},"legSequenceIndex":10,"departureAirport":{"airportCode":"ABE","airportCity":"Allentown","airportName":"Allentown (ABE)","airportCityState":"Allentown, PA"},"departureDateFormat":"2012/02/09","arrivalDateFormat":"Feb. 9","formattedDepartureTime":"12:07pm","formattedArrivalTime":"7:35pm","hasTrainLeg":false,"stops":2,"totalTravelingHours":{"hours":8,"minutes":28},"formattedMiles":"1,581","hasBusLeg":false,"formattedDepartureDate":"2/9/12","formattedDepartureDateTime":"2/9/12","departureDateFormat1":"Thu. Feb. 9","formattedArrivalDate":"2/9/12","durationTimeInMins":508,"locationDistanceCount":1581,"locationDistanceUnit":"miles","seatMapAvailableForAnySegment":true,"firstBagFreeAirlines":false,"showOBFeeMessageForLeg":false,"airlineWithBagFeeMsg":false,"airlineWithNoBagFeeMsg":false,"legIndex":1}],"inboundLegsInfo":[{"taxes":43.22,"basePrice":808.01,"taxesAndFees":50.22,"ceilTotalPrice":859.0,"localeFormattedTaxAndFees":"$50","localeFormatBasePrice":"$808","bookingFee":7.0,"t":858.23,"ft":"$858","fab":"$808","fat":"$858","faf":"$50","tripId":39,"s":2,"c":"DL"},{"taxes":43.22,"basePrice":808.01,"taxesAndFees":50.22,"ceilTotalPrice":859.0,"localeFormattedTaxAndFees":"$50","localeFormatBasePrice":"$808","bookingFee":7.0,"t":858.23,"ft":"$858","fab":"$808","fat":"$858","faf":"$50","tripId":39,"s":2,"c":"AA"}],"airFareBasisCode":"QA00A0NJ","flightFareType":"PUBLISHED","seatCount":1,"totalPrice":858.23,"fare":{"maxLccPrice":0.0,"minLccPrice":0.0,"totalFlightFare":858.23,"currencyCode":"USD","fees":{"amount":7.00,"currency":"USD","double":7.0,"currencyCode":"USD"},"taxes":{"amount":43.22,"currency":"USD","double":43.22,"currencyCode":"USD"},"baseFare":{"amount":808.01,"currency":"USD","double":808.01,"currencyCode":"USD"},"totalFare":{"amount":858.23,"currency":"USD","double":858.23,"currencyCode":"USD"},"totalBaseFare":808.01,"localeTotalBaseFare":"$808","localeTotalFlightTaxes":"$43","totalFlightTaxes":43.22,"localeTotalFlightFare":"$858","localeTotalFees":"$7","localeTotalFlightTaxesAndFees":"$50","totalFees":7.0,"totalTaxesAndFees":{"amount":50.22,"currency":"USD","double":50.22,"currencyCode":"USD"},"flightFare":{"currencyCode":"USD","basePrice":808.01,"taxes":43.22}},"flightId":"39","showFareDisplayName":false,"fareDisplayName":"Published","firstBagFreeAirline":false,"operatedByFeeDisplayFeatureEnabled":false,"hasFare":true,"localeFormatAvgBasePrice":"$808","localeFormatAvgTotalPrice":"$858","stops":2,"bargainFare":false,"fareName":"published","selectedFlightPara":"39:39:FLTIStr","fareTypeCode":"P","airProviderId":2,"ccfeeAirline":"","displayLCCFareName":false,"noOfTicketsLeft":1,"seatPreview":true,"localeFormatAvgTotalTaxesAndFees":"$50","priceIllegal":false,"fareTypeValue":"1","showOBFeeMessageForModule":false,"completeTrip":false,"hasAirlineWithBagFee":false,"hasAirlineWithNoBagFee":false,"isABestTrip":true,"carrierList":["DL","AA"],"isFirstBagFreePos":true},
```

...so on

Answer (score 2):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) takes a second parameter to return data as an associative array instead of objects. This will solve your problem.

```
$json_array = json_decode($string,true); // returns 'normal' php array.
$json       = json_decode($string);      // returns php object hierarchy
```

Answer (score 0):

http://json.parser.online.fr/ reports that you data ends unexpectedly. Do you actually have the real data? Or if is it wrong, how did you generate it? There might be errors in the generation script cause it is not complete...

There seems to be a misplaced character at the end. Instead of a comma ",", it should be a closing array "]"

Comment: yea...its not complete because of the post size limit...I just posted the "legs"(only a few) which is the main elements that have all the other data.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say WHY json_decode isn't working. If the JSON is too big to post here just use pastebin or something alike.

I assume the reason it's not working is because you are exceeding the memory allowance for PHP, you can work around this by increasing the max memory PHP can use, eg:

ini_set('memory_limit','16M');

However I wouldn't recommend doing this if this code is going to be ran by a large amount of users. Maybe if you give us some context we can give you an alternative solution which bypasses the need of json_decode.

Comment: json_decode works.... I am unable to access anything inside of the $json variable... can you show me an example with the above set of data...the root element is "legs"

Comment: json_decode works....i said it doesn't return null... and then var_dump prints the $json...but how can I access what is inside of the $json... $json[0]['segments']['layover']['hours'] when echoed is nothing...says illegal access error...how come??? how do I access this a value?